# Changing the Continue Shopping Button URL in Magento

Tags: cart

How do I change where the continue shopping button is redirecting my customers to?

Answer (score 2):

It is set dynamically in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart::getContinueShoppingUrl()` depending of some conditions.

The easiest way to customise it is to set it explicitly in the `checkout/cart.phtml` template of your theme.

The more sophisticated way would be to add something like this into your module controller:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setContinueShoppingUrl(...);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. Can you elaborate a little more ? This type of customization is new to me and I'm not sure where I should add the code.

Comment: That's quite easy. Locate `checkout/cart.phtml` file of your theme and change the link there.

Comment: hi @tim thanks for the response. so I should change it to a hard link or replace it with 

'Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setContinueShoppingUrl(...);'

Comment: If you have not much Magento experience I would suggest a hardlink. Where do you want to link?